# Different hostnames, same configuration

Tags: hostname

I set up two Ubuntu 20.04 servers to run Pi-hole for my home network. One is running on a Raspberry Pi 4 and the other is virtual. Both are running Ubuntu Server 20.04.

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
```

My issue is that one of them displays the fully qualified name when I do network scans, the other just displays the hostname.

Like when I do an IP scan using Angry IP Scanner:

```
IP             HOSTNAME
192.168.1.1    pihole-1
192.168.1.2    pihole-2.domain.com
```

What causes that and can I do something to get them both to read the full name?

```
#:hostname --fqdn
pihole-1

#:hostnamectl
   Static hostname: pihole-1
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 2e1eaf
           Boot ID: e04d31
    Virtualization: oracle
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-72-generic
      Architecture: x86-64

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 pihole-1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

```
hostname --fqdn
#:pihole-2

$hostnamectl
   Static hostname: pihole-2
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 2065184
           Boot ID: b3ed805
    Virtualization: oracle
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-72-generic
      Architecture: x86-64

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 pihole-2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Thanks

Comment: Without looking to hard at the details, my first thought would be... is the VM host running on the machine you are scanning from? The can might not be resolving it _if_ it sees the VM is on the same host or network. (I.E., it treats the domain name as a presumed already known fact, because you already know your own host.domain...) Have you checked if there is an option to force it to always resolve/display the FQDN?

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I didn't even think of that.